# Transmission freeze / no way out

Tags: mac, launchd, torrent

Sometimes Transmission.app freezes / hangs. These are known issues and they sure need to be reported to the Transmission project. However, I encountered a situation which is a system-wide bug.
macOS 10.12.6

The application dot in the Dock is on and is not responding. Force quit doesn't help. `ps ax` doesn't show this process. Neither does `launchctl list`. Neither does Activity Monitor.app. I don't know any other way to kill a process that simply doesn't exist. However, it prevents a reboot and cannot be relaunched or deleted (Finder says it's open). The only way is to hard-reset the machine. Any ideas?

`killall Finder` & `kilall Dock` does nothing.

Comment: Have you tried the terminal commands `sudo shutdown -h now` (shuts down) or `sudo shutdown -r now` (reboots)?

Comment: I don't want to reboot, I want to kill and restart the process. In any OS that should be possible without a reboot.

Comment: I gave you these commands in case you want to actually reboot or shutdown instead of holding down the power button (hard-reset) which can cause problems sometimes. That's all. If you can't find the process to kill it, you have no other recourse. Also, you neglected to mention which version of macOS you're running on this Mac.

Comment: It's macOS 10.12.6 as stated in the OP. I can reset the computer, but the reason why I was asking in the first place, I want to increase my knowledge on macOS process management and understand how to deal with it. The only application causing this strange state is Transmission. I wonder if it's a OS bug or there is some way to find and kill it.

Comment: Understood. I think you need to talk with Transmission support to find out more about this problem.

Comment: I reported it to no avail. But I've posted the question here because it's an OS issue, Transmission just happened to cause it.